# Android Studio 2.3 gradle error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

After Android Studio update to 2.3, I'm getting the following error.

### Console output message

> Error:Unable to load class 'org.gradle.logging.StyledTextOutput'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

---

### Tried to fix

- I've tried to invalidate cache and restart.
- Use default gradle
  wrapper

Someone getting the same error?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try to check all your dependencies in `build.gradle` and update them if needed. In my case updating dexcount gradle plugin solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you! That was the reason for me I updated from `0.5.4` to `0.6.2`

Comment: Any idea, why dex-count caused this problem, and why updating the library fixed that?

Comment: that was also it for me - went from 0.5.0 to 0.6.2.. oh goodness, thank you, I can deploy the right apk without restarting again!!

Comment: Reference this page to get the most recent version for dex-count https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.getkeepsafe.dexcount%3Adexcount-gradle-plugin

Comment: Awesome! how can I live without stackoverflow? :D

Comment: Here you can find the latest version for `dexcount-gradle-plugin`: https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin

Comment: Thank you! I had the same problem with dex-count.

Comment: I have deleted all dependencies, and disabled all plugins and am getting the same error. I've tried clearing cache, manually downloading gradle, restarted several times, I cannot get rid of this error. Is there anything else that might cause this?

Answer (score 2):

After update to Android Studio 2.3, the gradle path wasn't update.

Try to check your settings:

[image: Try to check your settings]

Comment: Why is this preferred to **default wrapper**?

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me. Upgrading from android studio 3.3 to 3.4 solved the problem.