# Android Studio 2.3 not displaying layout designs

Tags: android, user-interface, android-studio, graphical-layout-editor, android-studio-2.3

I've just upgraded to Android Studio 2.3, but when I try to display this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/transparent"
        android:background="@color/transparent"

        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_album_radius">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/alarm"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/toolbar_alarm"
                android:alpha="0.35"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/songs_count_padding_bottom"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/songs_count_padding_bottom"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/alarm"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/songs_count"
                tools:text="Sample Title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16sp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textColor="@color/album_title"
                android:textSize="@dimen/note_card_title"
                android:textStyle="normal"

                />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/overflow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_dots" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I receive this error from interface designer (layout editor):

```
The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
```

Clicking on `Fix Build Path` or other links has no effect.

Comment: Are all required Support Libraries (v7) present on your build.gradle file? Seems like they can't be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem :

Change your style parent to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` instead of `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` in styles.xml......... it worked for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40067731/305135

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your dependencies. After update to Android Studio 2.3, my gradle broke.

[See details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42681258/2430481)